# AngularJS Hello World in IE11

Tags: angularjs

The following code works fine in Safari and Chrome but not in IE11. Can anyone help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-init="name = 'World'">
    <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried and it works fine in ie11. Are you running this file locally?

Comment: I've just run it on IE11 and it does work. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/nTHcSNfn6zZVhnEa4EIs?p=preview

Comment: Hi Chandermani - yes - running from my filesystem. Added a HTML page into a new VS2013 project and ran from that environment direct via IE11. Also tried running directly from the file on my filesystem with same result. Modified code to the following with same result:

Comment: <!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.google.apis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js">
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-init="name = 'World'">
    <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

IE blocks the script (Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or Active X controls) if you open it from the filesystem.

After allowing script content on this site, IE11 works too.

See http://jsfiddle.net/n8aqL/ (it works when served via a http server)

```
//Hello, World!
```

You can change the local blocking scripts in IE11 in Internet Options -> Advanced -> Settings -> Security -> "Allow active content to run my files on My Computer"

Comment: Hi danimajo - could you tell me how to allow IE11 to allow script content.  I have set that on the security options for both Internet and Intranet and it still doesn't run the script.

Comment: Hi danimajo - you are brilliant.  That sorted my problem.  Default for IE11 is to not allow this content to run.  Changed the setting and it works fine now. Changed it back just to test and it fails again. 100% correct answer to my problem - very happy.